# Website viewed in Google Chrome displays weird code

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, browser

Attempting to view my site on Google Chrome and occasionally I will get the following code displayed to me. This is a Wordpress site and it works great on other browsers, as well other users viewing in Chrome don't see this (that I know of).

Any idea what this code actually is and what might be causing it?

See a screenshot of what I'm getting here: http://s24.postimg.org/m93wtt26d/search_beauty_code.png

I'm using Google Chrome Version 26.0.1410.65 on a Mac

Comment: You should provide a link to you website in order to ease investigations.

Comment: Here is a link to the dev site: [link](http://www.adwalla.com/SearchBeauty/)

Answer (score 1):

Your file has a wrong character encoding. The real encoding is "ascii-us" whereas the HTTP header and the meta tag declare the encoding as UTF-8.

First, you should try to set the wordpress default theme to see if the theme is the issue. If not, then try to check you apache configuration to understand why the document is encoded that way.

You could also try to change the meta tag (in you theme) to `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ascii-us" />`, and the HTTP header `Content-Type` accordingly (via .htaccess).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, turns out this was an issue with a particular plugin for the wordpress theme that I'm using. I appreciate your help in this matter though.

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Type` header is not set in the server for that file.

Try to edit your .htaccess or PHP-code (when this content is being created/relayed by PHP) to include this header.

Comment: The HTTP `Content-Type` header is set to `text/html; charset=UTF-8`